# Is it possible to use Google Sheets instead of/with an Node.JS/ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, node.js, google-sheets

Building a realtime management system for a sales team with a REST API from their WordPress site. The functionality they want is basically Google Sheets with some custom connections/communication.

Looked in to the Google Sheets API 4, but to me it looks non customizable to the extend i want it to be.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Thinking of building it from scratch with Node.JS or ASP.NET Core and is looking for a framework alternatively something like Google Sheets that is customizable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

For example you can use one of these module:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-sheets

Read this tutorial - 
Node.js Quickstart for the Google Sheets API:

- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs